# Problematic Cookie class binding with Jetty 8

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, cookies, jetty-8

I'm trying to upgrade Jetty version from 7.4 to one compliant with servlet 3.0 specification like 8.1.4, as well as GWT from 2.3 to 2.5.

While doing so, I found that jetty's Response.addCookie(Cookie) method calls for a method in Cookie class that hasn't been declared or implemented, resulting in the following error:

```
javax.servlet.http.Cookie.isHttpOnly()Z
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.addCookie(Response.java:161)
```

I already checked, and servlet-3.0's Cookie class has the isHttp() method, but gwt-user.jar has another implementation not compliant with servlet 3.0(meaning it doesn't define that method, as well as some others).

At this point, I'm not sure to what code it's binding, and I can't debug the code(it is executed in a server for which I can only access log files and jars)

Changing the order of dependencies in the pom file proved unsuccessful, so I've run out of ideas.

PD: There is also a dependency for j2ee-1.4 jar, which has a Cookie class not compliant with Servlet 3.0

Comment: Try upgrading to GWT 2.6, it comes with Jetty 8.1 and servlet 3.0 (vs. Jetty 6 in previous versions of GWT)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Upgrading to versions greater that 2.5.0 results in an error when finding entry point classes. Since the people I work for aren't fond of big changes, I would like to keep things the way they are. The only reason they allowed this upgrade is because there were some security issues that needed to be addressed

Comment: The Web changes face every few months; GWT 2.5.0 is more than a year old (nearly a year and a half!) and the Web has met IE10 and IE11 in the mean time. As hard as it can be, you should aim at upgrading to the latest version as soon as it gets out the door.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I added a question regarding the issues with changing to gwt 2.6. Would you take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888983/entry-points-after-migrating-from-gwt-2-3-to-2-6