# Entry points after migrating from GWT 2.3 to 2.6

Tags: gwt

I have 2 projects with the following structure

> Project 1
>
> - com/MyCompany/MyApp/UI/MyAppUI.gwt.xml
> - com/MyCompany/MyApp/UI/client/MyApp.java (Entry Point class)
>
> Project 2
>
> - com/MyCompany/MyApp/UI/MyAppUI.gwt.xml

The first project contains all server and client side code and compiles to a jar, and the second one only contains a basic html page, css and images and compiles to a war.

Before upgrading, the second project's gwt.xml file simply declared the entry point class of the first one, and since they both had the same module name I assume the gwt compiler joined them together and compiled it all to the war file.

If I keep the project structure I get a compilation error stating it couldn't find the Entry point in the given directory(I assume it is looking for it in the second project), and if I change it the war file doesn't contain any of the javascript compiled code that should be in it.

What I need to do is make the second project declare the first project's entry point as its own. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

PD: I am not authorized to merge it all into a single project or perform any major changes of the sort, I have to make do with what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to modify the pom file of Project 2 to include all necessary classes from Project 1

```
      <directory>${basedir}/../MyCompany/src/main/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/ui/*.java</include>
        <include>**/*.css</include>
        <include>**/ui/*.gwt.xml</include>
        <include>**/ui/**/*.java</include>
      </includes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the same module name (with the same path) is certainly not a good idea - I wonder, why that would have worked with GWT 2.3?

So in your second project, choose a different name for your module, and `<inherit>` the module from the first project (if that is what you want to do).

Also, if there is client side stuff in the first project, make sure you include the source java files in the jar of the first project.

Comment: It worked because classpath precedence, and it probably fails for the same reason.

Comment: Solved it. Problem and solution was in the pom file of the project. I modified the <includes> to pick up every class inside the ui folder. No idea why it worked before. Thanks Chris and Thomas for your help